# How to send mails with .NET non-reverse-engineerably?

Tags: c#, .net, email, security

Here's this snippet:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword"),
    EnableSsl = true,
};

var msg = new MailMessage()
{
    From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com"),
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
};
msg.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");

client.Send(msg);
```

The problem with this is that **"mypassword"** is easily **reverse-engineerable** from the application, isn't it?

If I'm right, then how can I prevent this?

Comment: What's the scenario you're trying to protect against? Just someone that gets their hands on your application code? Or are you trying to protect against someone that can read the application memory as it's running?

Comment: The second one: decompiling the DLL-s, runtime analysing application memory, etc.

Comment: Example code ("how to protect secrets in client side code") is very different from what you claim to ask in the "decompiling the DLL-s, runtime analysing application memory, etc" comment... Please think about what you want and consider to [edit] question (obviously you've already looked at many questions asking about obfuscation and protecting secrets, so may be good idea to show your research as part of the edit too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store it in a server and deliver it to your app through an API. That way you don't give the user access to your password and if your server is a secure server it's a lot less likely that they can get to it.

EDIT: When I say *deliver it* I'm refering to deliver the object, or in this case you can have the whole method on the API, which you just call from your app and just return a boolean or something to get feedback on wether it sent the e-mail successfully or not.

Comment: good start as "store password on a server"... compensating for awful suggestion to "deliver it to your app"... So marginally better than flat out wrong idea of encrypting settings to "protect" them as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, perhaps I miscomunicated... by it, I was refering to the information, or object, in this case, or just downright the entire send email method. Not the password. That would defeat the purpose of the secure server.

Comment: I solved it with having a Firebase function which sends emails :)

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** If the application is running on a machine that you can't secure, your password cannot be fully protected.

Even if you encrypt the password, store it in a secure store, or retrieve it from a secure service, that password will still live in the local computer's memory, which a malicious user can dump and parse to find it. Or they could hook up Wireshark or Fiddler and sniff the password off of the wire (yes, even if you are using `EnableSsl = true`).

The best way to deal with this situation is either

(1) Give each user an account and password just for them

(2) Move the functionality off the client and onto a server that is secure

Answer (score -4):

Simple solution is to put the credential in the appSettings of web.config or app.config, the then your program get the credential from the config.

You can also encrypt the appSettings like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v%3Dvs.100))

Comment: This is only a secure solution if you assume the app is on a secure server. If it's a desktop app you'll have to keep that file locally and so the user will get easy access to it.

Comment: Yes, I only consider this app is work on secure server, not the desktop.